# Relation between 2-norm and F-norm

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-norms

$\|A\|_2 = \sup_{\|x\|_2 = 1} \|Ax\|_2 = \sup_{\|x\|_2 = 1} \|Ax\|_F$

since **A** is a matrix and x is a vector, then $Ax$ is a vector.
And we have that $\|x\|_2 = \|x\|_F$, right?

Comment: Yes, the Frobenius norm and Euclidean norm are the same for vectors (i.e. $n \times 1$ matrices). This is because the Frobenius norm is a generalization of the Euclidean norm for matrices, while the Euclidean norm is specifically a vector norm

Comment: Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you mean by $F$ the **Frobenius** norm then yes  $\vert \vert x\vert \vert$$_F$$=$$\vert \vert x\vert \vert$$_2$

Comment: Yes that is right. Thank you!